# Match week Names with week Days in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, datetime

I am trying to make a calendar with HTML, CSS and PHP. And so far, it went well. But at the end, I discovered that I forgot that months not always starts on a monday.

[image]

How would I do this? I am not that strong in PHP, and cant really figure out how I would do it.

This month for example *(December)*, I would need to add 5 "hidden or disabled" days infront, to match that **December 1st** is a Saturday.

```
<!-- Week Days -->
<ul class="weekdays">
    <li>Monday</li>
    <li>Tuesday</li>
    <li>Wednesday</li>
    <li>Thursday</li>
    <li>Friday</li>
    <li>Saturday</li>
    <li>Sunday</li>
</ul>
<!-- Days -->
<ul class="days"> 
<?php

    // Make List
    $list = array();
    $month = date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));
    $year = date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'));

    for($d = 1; $d <= 31; $d++){
        $time = mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);    

        if(date('m', $time) == $month)       
            $list[] = date('d', $time);
    }
    if(is_array($list) || is_object($list)){
        foreach($list as $day){

            if($day < date('d')){
                echo '<li class="passed"><span>' . $day . '</span></li>';
            }else if($day == date('d')){
                echo '<li class="current"><span>' . $day . '</span></li>';
            }else{
                echo '<li><span>' . $day . '</span></li>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: December has **31** days.

Comment: Damn, you have a point...

Comment: @KoshVery Found the problem on that. Minus on the months and Year. Dont know why I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your example, you are actually outputting the information for November 2017, which starts on a Wednesday.

To achieve what you are looking for, you simply need to find out what day of the week it is and then add additional 'empty' items to your `$list` array if you need to pad the month.

To find out the day of the week use:

```
... // Your existing code under Make List
$year = date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'));

$date = '01-' . $month . '-' . $year;
$dayofweek = date('w', strtotime($date));
```

Now `$dayofweek` will contain the numeric number of the week, with 0 being Sunday, 1 being Monday, and so on.

Next, just add empty items into your list array to pad the number of days that should be empty:

```
if ($dayofweek == 0) $dayofweek = 7;
for (; $dayofweek > 1; $dayofweek--)
    $list[] = '';
```

Note that where the start day is Sunday, I change this to 7 to cause the padding of 6 boxes.

Finally, when you output your list items, just add an empty day `<li>` for each padded day:

```
... // Your existing code
foreach($list as $day){
    if ($day == '')
        echo '<li>Empty day</li>';
    else if($day < date('d')){
        ... // Your existing code continues
```

Comment: Not sure if its me doing it wrong, but i only get 1 extra infront. Not the 5 I need? The "if ($dayofweek == 0) $dayofweek = 7;...." part, where do I include/replace with that? :-)

Comment: Put the for loop directly after the `$dayofweek = date(...)` line.  The number of paddings will depend on the month and year you are using.  In your original example it was November 2017 (padding of 2).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for this example is to restructure your code around the calendar weeks instead of the days. The code below should help you do that, but you will need to finish the rest of the code to display it however you want.

```
$currentMonth = date('m');
    $daysInMonth = date('t');
    $currentDay = 0;
    $firstOfMonthDay = date('w', strtotime('2017-01-01'));
    nextWeek = true;


    while(nextWeek){ // displays weekly fields
        counter = 1;
        while(counter <= 7){ // displays empty box or date
            formatBox();
            if($firstOfMonthDay == $counter){
                // starts printing date
                $currentDay++;
            }
            if($currentDay > 0 && $currentDay <= $daysInMonth){
                // prints date while the month has valid days
                printDay();
            }
            $currentDay++;
            counter++;
        }
        if($currentDay < $daysInMonth){
            // stops printing new weeks when there are no more valid
            // days in the month
            nextWeek = false;
        }
    }
```